# Как запускать npm-скрипт по расписанию

Tags: node.js, bash, npm

Есть тесты на jest, которые нужно запускать на сервере каждые 10 минут. Запускаются они c помощью npm-команды `npm run test`.

Как сделать так, чтобы эта команда срабатывала каждый раз через определенный промежуток времени?

`package.json` соответственно такой:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "jest"
  },
```

Думал для этого подойдет `node-cron`, но не нашел возможности там запускать именно npm-команды.

Comment: программа-планировщик `cron` может помочь в решении вашей проблемы

Comment: а можно пожалуйста конкретней, как это сделать именно касательно npm-скрипта?

Comment: А в чём проблема использовать `crontab`? o_O

Comment: `*/10 * * * * cd /path/to/project && npm run test >> /dev/null 2>&1`

Comment: Можно использовать `systemd timers`: https://habr.com/ru/company/ruvds/blog/512868/